# how to invoke setter method by reflection in java

Tags: java, spring

how to invoke Bean private setter method by reflection in java

I can't Understand how to invoke private setter Method in My User Bean.
I all ready used PropertyDescriptor and many way but i am not access private 
 setter method by the Reflection.

```
public class GetterAndSetter
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         GetterAndSetter gs = new GetterAndSetter();
         User user = new User();

          try {
            gs.callSetter(user,"name","Sanket");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }

     private void callSetter(Object obj,String fieldName, Object value) throws IntrospectionException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException , IllegalArgumentException
     {
         PropertyDescriptor pd;

         pd = new PropertyDescriptor(fieldName,obj.getClass());
         pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(obj,value);
     }

 }
```

This Code I would only access the filed and set the value in filed,But  I can't 
access the setter Field directly to the Reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how you can call a private method in the `User` class:

```
try {
    User user = new User();
    Method method = User.class.getDeclaredMethod("setName", String.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(user, "Some name");
    System.out.println("user.getName() = " + user.getName());
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note the call to `method.setAccessible(true);`

Comment: You Right I can access those private method But Suppose I have a User class with two Filed name & age this filed have setter and getter method Then i can try to set the value directly in Setter Method not in filed Method Please Let me know how it possible

Comment: If I understood ur question correctly, all u need to do is to change the `User.class.getDeclaredMethod("setName", String.class);` to `User.class.getDeclaredMethod("setAge", Integer.class);`. You can modify your callSetter method and pass the required parameters to it.

Comment: hi this code is hardcode User.class.getDeclaredMethod("setName", 
                      String.class); 
                     User.class.getDeclaredMethod("setAge", Integer.class);  i want not 
                     declared and specify anything like String.class then invoke setter

Comment: To make it reusable you can modify your `callSetter` method and replace what it's doing with my approach.

Comment: I Completly Agree with you but in this   User.class.getDeclaredMethod("setName", String.class);  we can specify the  parameterTypes that was hard code any other way we can not hard code the parameter type or easy invoke method

Comment: Pass `String.class` as a parameter to callSetter. Its type will be `java.lang.Class`.