# How to set the values directly in private Setter method in bean class by using Reflection in java

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I can't set the the values directly in Setter Method of my User bean class using reflection

I can only access those getter method but i can't set the value in the 
 Setter method of User Bean Class.

[how to invoke setter method by reflection in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049322/how-to-invoke-setter-) 
 method-by-reflection-in-java

```
 //------->This My UserClass

public class User {

     private String name;
     private int age;

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    private void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    private void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }
 }
 //------> Then My Main Method 

 public static void main(String args[])
{
 try {
    User user = new User();
    Method method = User.class.getDeclaredMethod("setName", String.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(user, "Some name");
    System.out.println("user.getName() = " + user.getName());
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I want call the Setter method directly in and set the value in Setter that changes can reflected in User Bean setter method. Please let me Know is that possible.

Comment: As `private` implies to only within the class, hence it is not possible.

Comment: But I want to set some value Directly in setter method is it possible that reflection on  setter method

Comment: `User` is not a Spring Bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your setName() method is set to private. You can not access any private methods of a class, outside that class itself.

Change it to..

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

And you will be good to go.

Comment: Suppose I can declared the setter as public then how can set the value in Setter by reflection

Comment: @sanketjaiswal The same way you worked above, just with the method as public.

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code and its working fine. Using Reflection api you can invoke the private methods by setAccessible as true.

Comment: you can set the value in private Setter method